# Can I get a latched topic with rosh?

Tags: ros, latch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've noticed that if I start up a node, create a latched publisher, and then publish a single message (let's say on the topic foo), if I then go into rosh and do topics.foo[0], it will just sit there blocking. According to rosh's documentation, this makes sense, but is there a way to get a latched topic at all in rosh?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30276/can-i-get-a-latched-topic-with-rosh?/) by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9115 on 2012-03-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's quite possible that latched topic support  was not added to rosh yet.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0